# Quartz Cron trigger firing multiple times only at a certian time

Tags: java, quartz

So we have a cron trigger that fires every hour 7 days a week.

On saturday at 1am UTC the trigger has been firing multiple times. This appears to be the only time it happens though, all other triggers fire once

Comment: Ok, bad for you :) How can we help you?

Comment: This lacks a clear question. And if you need to know why what you observed happened, please provide code samples, config, logs, anything really that could help pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

its better to see some sample snippet of quartz and trigger config code